# What program could I use to make animated vector icon constructions?

Tags: vector, icon, animation, illustration

I've created some vector icons in Illustrator. Recently I found [this designer's work](https://dribbble.com/kairevicius) and was intrigued by his animated constructions, like the following:
[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/2477055-Cloud-Icon]
[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/2059252-Eye-Constructions]

I've contacted the artist to ask about his animation process but haven't received a response. So, I thought I would ask for input on here.

Does anyone know what program might be used to make animations like these?

Caveat: I know how to make gifs in Photoshop. I was wondering if there is a program that can animate vector shapes.

I have access to all of Adobe's Creative Cloud programs, so if any of those programs can be used, that would be my first choice. Thanks

Comment: After effects is your best bet. Though any text editor could be made to do the same if your down on luck.

Answer (score 1):

That is an animated gif. The final output is not a vector.

To animate vectors as such you could use some web animation technique, like animating with CSS or JavaScript. Or use **Flash** or **Adobe Animate**. All this for web application.

Some programs produce at the end a bitmap output, like the animated gif itself, a video or Html5 Canvas.

But we need to differentiate drawing vectors as a tool and making animations that look as vectors. This example is the second one.

So, you can use **After effects**, which is a compositing tool.

A good news. You can use some free tools.

- **HitFilmExpress**: https://hitfilm.com/express (Both Mac and PC) Output Video that can be converted to an animated gif.
- **Express Animate**: http://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/ (Just for Windows) Video, direct animated gif or Canvas Output.
- You could also adapt **Blender** to render 2D looking animations.
- A flash like program is **Synfig** http://synfig.org/
- And other option for html5 animation: **Google web designer**: https://www.google.com/webdesigner/
- If you want to animate using a JavaScript library this is an interesting option. http://greensock.com/

---

And take a look at some other options: http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-flash/

---

Also this can be animated using only CSS animation https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=css+animation